# Anaconda Scikit-learn latest version

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I can't update my anaconda environment to scikit-learn 0.22 using the terminal. I have version 0.21.3 currently installed and each time I try to upgrade it conda seems to see that I have the latest version available.

Comment: please add details. E.g., OS, Python version, Conda version